# On my machine I don't have visual studio, is it possible to use GIT for PL-SQL files?

Tags: git

One of my team members are not using visual studio they are all Pl-SQL developer and another team members are .Net developers. I am interested to use GIT VCS. Is it possible to use GIT for PL-SQL files / general file types (.docx, .txt, .pdf, .pptx)? Tell me HOW? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Just as you do for regular code files like `.js` or `.java` files, you just need to `git add .`, `git commit -m "<commit message here>"` `git push <name of remote> <name of branch>`.

Comment: Thank you Neeraj, Is any tool require to access these files on w/o Visual studio machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use GIT for the files you mentioned.

As mentioned in the comments by @Neeraj you just need to do

- git add
- git commit -m ""
- git push

Comment: Thank you setshaft your answer mostly solved my doubt, can you pls suggest me a good tutorial / Material to use GIT for .Net projects?

Comment: I don't think you need to learn Git in a specific way to use it with .net projects or any other projects. Git is version control system and works completely fine with almost any type of project you can imagine. You can look [here](https://learngitbranching.js.org/) and [here](https://try.github.io/) to learn basics.